# How do I "tree shake" an internal QA page in Flutter release mode?

Tags: flutter

I want to create an internal QA page that toggles API urls between develop, staging, and production. I want this to be accessed only in debug mode via a long press gesture. How do I ensure that this code and widget files get removed in release mode?
Will using `assert` do this for me?